# Marshaling Detail Record without having rid literal

Tags: java, bean-io

I have a fixed length file with the following format.

X - Header

Y - Trailer

Data records does not have any identifier literal as the first character.

**Sample Data:**

```
X10506505
RANDOM00 DATA1
RANDOM00 DATA2
Y0000001
```

Header record is parsed fine.

**Issue**: Trailer record is getting mapped to the detail record as the detail record does not have any unique identifier.

How do I distinguish trailer record from detail record?

Comment: What is the probability that the detail records will start with either 'X' or 'Y'?

Comment: It has a 100%  chance for trailer and header records to start with X/Y..

Comment: I was thinking that you could maybe use a regular expression to say anything that doesn't start with the header and trailer ids is the detail record. Sorry, other than that, there isn't really a way to identify the detail records.

Comment: What if the detail record starts with "Z" or "X"? We have to consider first and last records to be headers and trailers.

Answer (score 0):

The following `mapping.xml` file works for me. You will see that I use `rid` on more than one field. This makes BeanIO use more data on line to identify the correct record.

```
<stream name="dummy" format="fixedlength" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" >
  <group name="myFile" class="com.company.project.File" >
    <record name="header" class="com.company.project.Header" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <field name="id" rid="true" length="1" required="true" literal="X" />
      <field name="h1" rid="true" length="8" required="true" regex=".{8}" />
      <field name="h2" length="4" required="false" minOccurs="0"/>
    </record>
    <record name="detailRecords" class="com.company.project.Detail" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" collection="collection">
      <field name="d1" rid="true" length="9" required="true" regex=".{8,9}" />
      <field name="d2" rid="true" length="5" required="true" regex=".{5}" /> 
      <field name="d3" length="5" required="false" minOccurs="0"/> 
    </record>  
    <record name="trailer" class="com.company.project.Trailer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <field name="id" rid="true" length="1" required="true" literal="Y" />
      <field name="tValue" rid="true" length="7" required="true" regex=".{7}" />
    </record>
  </group>
</stream>
```

If this doesn't work for you, I would need more specific details of the data and if possible, actual data.

**Test 1:**

```
X10506505
RANDOM00 DATA1
RANDOM00 DATA2
Y0000001
```

**Output:**

```
Header: id='X', h1='10506505'
Detail: d1='RANDOM00', d2='DATA1'
Detail: d1='RANDOM00', d2='DATA2'
Trailer: id='Y', tValue='0000001'
```

**Test 2:**

```
X10506505
RANDOM00 DATA1
RANDOM00 DATA2
XANDOM00 DATA3
YANDOM00 DATA4
Y0000001
```

**Output:**

```
Header: id='X', h1='10506505'
Detail: d1='RANDOM00', d2='DATA1'
Detail: d1='RANDOM00', d2='DATA2'
Detail: d1='XANDOM00', d2='DATA3'
Detail: d1='YANDOM00', d2='DATA4'
Trailer: id='Y', tValue='0000001'
```

Thanks must also go to a colleague (Malcolm McLean) for his help.